# When I use positional-only arguments with annotations in Python 3.8, I get a symtable that seems incorrect

Tags: python, python-internals, python-3.8

Python 3.8 has a new syntax feature for [positional-only function arguments](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0570/). When I use this feature in conjunction with annotations, and produce a symbol table for the code, a symbol seems to be missing.

Without positional-only args:

```py
>>> import symtable
>>> symtable.symtable('def f(x: y): pass', '?', 'exec').get_symbols()
[<symbol 'f'>, <symbol 'y'>]
```

This is expected. `f` and `y` are symbols in the global scope. Now I'm adding a `/` to mark the argument positional-only:

```py
>>> symtable.symtable('def f(x: y, /): pass', '?', 'exec').get_symbols()
[<symbol 'f'>]
```

**This seems wrong.** Symbol `y` is missing, although it's still an annotation of `x` and should therefore still be present in the root symtable. Is this an internal bug, or am I missing side-effects of this new feature?

(I'm using CPython 3.8.0.)

Comment: Have you considered creating an issue on the [Python issue tracker](https://bugs.python.org/)?

Comment: @MSeifert Will do.

Comment: Update on this? I can't reproduce the behavior, did it get fixed?

Answer (score 1):

This was fixed in Python 3.8.x (can't figure out the exact version bisecting) and all stable 3.9~3.12 versions so no longer a problem.

```
❯❯❯ python3.8 -c "import sys, symtable; print(sys.version.split()[0], symtable.symtable('def f(x: y, /): pass', '?', 'exec').get_symbols())"
3.8.18 [<symbol 'f'>, <symbol 'y'>]

❯❯❯ python3.9 -c "import sys, symtable; print(sys.version.split()[0], symtable.symtable('def f(x: y, /): pass', '?', 'exec').get_symbols())"
3.9.18 [<symbol 'f'>, <symbol 'y'>]

❯❯❯ python3.10 -c "import sys, symtable; print(sys.version.split()[0], symtable.symtable('def f(x: y, /): pass', '?', 'exec').get_symbols())"
3.10.13 [<symbol 'f'>, <symbol 'y'>]

❯❯❯ python3.11 -c "import sys, symtable; print(sys.version.split()[0], symtable.symtable('def f(x: y, /): pass', '?', 'exec').get_symbols())"
3.11.5 [<symbol 'f'>, <symbol 'y'>]
```